# Set JavaFx ComboBox Font?

Tags: fonts, combobox, javafx-2

Im trying to change a ComboBox Font on JavaFx, so I have:

> `ComboBox cbCategoria = new ComboBox();`

Im new in javaFx so some example code would be great :D,
Is a Way to do it without CSS? and if not how can i make it with CSS,I havent learned how to use CSS Styling yet :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is no way to do it without CSS. You can assign the style to that component as in the next sample:

```
VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

ComboBox<String> noStyled = new ComboBox<>();
noStyled.getItems().addAll("One", "Two", "Three");

ComboBox<String> styled = new ComboBox<>();
styled.setPrefWidth(150);
styled.getItems().addAll("One", "Two", "Three");
styled.setStyle("-fx-font: 30px \"Serif\";");

vbox.getChildren().addAll(noStyled, styled);
Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Or you can assign a stylesheet to an application. In both cases  I recommend you to go through the [tutorial CSS Section](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm) in the oracle web site and the [reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

ComboBox<String> noStyled = new ComboBox<>();
noStyled.getItems().addAll("One", "Two", "Three");

ComboBox<String> styled = new ComboBox<>();
styled.setPrefWidth(150);
styled.getItems().addAll("One", "Two", "Three");
styled.setStyle("-fx-font: 30px \"Serif\";");

vbox.getChildren().addAll(noStyled, styled);
Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();
```

Just for suggetion.
if you want to set size of combobox using above code.you should try like this

```
styled.setPrefWidth(150);
styled.setMinHeight(30);
```

Instead of,

```
 styled.setPrefSize(150,30);
```

If you set like this, you'll get exception. 
I faced hard time about this.
Hope it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

// I havent learned how to use CSS Styling yet :( //

--> Then you can try this

```
ComboBox cbCategoria = new ComboBox();
cbCategoria.getEditor().setFont(Font.font("Verdana", FontWeight.EXTRA_BOLD, 14));
```